# How to Integrate CCAvenue with .Net Core API and angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, ccavenue

I am developing an angular website with ASP.Net Core 2.0 for web API. I want to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway. Can you provide any reference? I searched for it on the internet but didn't find anything useful

Comment: Yes, I am working on integration of CC Avenue payment gateway in Angular 5 with  ASP.Net Core 2.0. within 1 week I will let you know exact solution of this integration. I am middle of integration.